# Why doesn't my WPF application show up?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have a WPF application developed and been testing already for a few months.
When it's installed on the client's computer the application starts and no window is visible. The task manager shows the application is running.

The application is writing all activities in few log files and it looks like it is doing something but no visible screen.

What can be a possible cause of the problem ?

Why it is invisible on that specific machine ? The machine is Windows 7 64x bit
The installed frameworks are v1.0 1.1 v2.0 v3.0 v3.5 v4.030319

The strange thing is the application was working before.

Comment: have you installed and tested it on yours?try to replicate the scenario on the users machine. Your answer lies thereabout possibly visibility property set to 0?window hidden?

Comment: Thanks you all guys. It is a kiosk application. I already have Browser.log, Kiosk.log, System.log and all are working fine. The application never goes to hidden state. The problem is even the Windows Event Log doesn't shows anything. I suppose the problem can be in some exception raised in Window Load event handler. It is possible that is caught in the application unhandled exception handler but never written to log. Strange.

Comment: The application was working before on that specific machine or on some other machine? If it never worked on that specific machine try installing the latest video drivers for that machine.

Comment: Are you using any third party tools?

Comment: The application was working on that machine but it looks like that something happened after power loss. I am using Awesomium web browser framework as third party tool.

Comment: I have seen, just today, the exact same problem on a WPF app of mine, when I tried to run it on a client machine. The main EXE loads, no DLLs seem to be loaded (while they should), the disk is used a bit, but no window. No events on EventViewer. The most weird of all is that I could not kill the running process using ProcessExplorer (even when running it as admin). Really a WTF situation... Something is broken on the system level for sure, but not sure what...

Answer (score 3):

You should check Windows Event log (Type eventvwr in run dialog or go to viewer by Computer Management dialog of Windows) to get info about the problem. The reason is most likely your application has an exception before your main window is opened. So you see that process is running in task manager but windows did not show up.

The reason in event log could be anything. May be your app requires a file in a specified path but not found. I meany anything that causes an except,on could be your problem.